# Compare grouped boxplot with Wilcoxon test

Tags: r, ggplot2, pairwise.wilcox.test

I want to add the wilcoxon test pvalue comparing the `g1 vs g2` on `Species` subgroups to the plot below my question.

In SO there were some similar questions like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/66627716/13046806 but the test doesn't compare 2 groups in multiples subgroups

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
iris$group=sample(c("g1","g2"),nrow(iris),replace = TRUE,)
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Species ,y=Sepal.Length, fill=group) )+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

the wilcoxon test should be something like this but ideally implemented in the ggplot pipe

```r
L=iris %>%
  group_split(Species)
 for (i in 1:length(L)) {
   df=L[[i]]
   sub_g=unique(df$Species)
   p=df%>%
   summarise(pvalue = wilcox.test( Sepal.Length~ group,exact = FALSE)$p.value)
   print(paste0(sub_g,": ",p))
 }
#> [1] "setosa: 0.976165659102827"
#> [1] "versicolor: 0.7475079522341"
#> [1] "virginica: 0.521330527688775"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: you want comparison between setosa(g1,g2)? if i see the code you are now specifying any test to compare here

Comment: yes i want to compare (g1, g2)

Comment: have a look at the code i guess that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new data frame with the p-values, and use it in a new `geom_text` layer:

```
irisp <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(wilcox.p = wilcox.test(Sepal.Length ~ group, exact = FALSE)$p.value)

ggplot(iris) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = group)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = Species,y = 3.8,label = paste0("p = ",round(wilcox.p,3))), irisp)
```

[image: grouped geom_boxplot with p-values as geom_text]

Answer (score 2):

This is one way perhaps that you need

```
 ggplot(iris, aes(x = group, y = Sepal.Length, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~Species, scales = "free") +
  stat_compare_means(aes(label = paste0("p = ", ..p.format..)),
                     method = "wilcox.test", label.y = 8)
```

Comment: that is not bad but coud the plot be unwrapped ?

Comment: that is what Im trying ,as of now my brain couldn't figure it out how to keep all of them together

Comment: @Wael https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446392/r-ggplot2-boxplots-with-significance-level-more-than-2-groups-kruskal-test-an?rq=1 this is one i found but again its using facet